# Check if adb is installed

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, I'd like to check if the `adb` command in a `cmd` is working (--> installed). I already tried to work with `system` and `process` but, wasn't able to get any information about if `adb` could be ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I can think of would be iterating over all directories in `PATH` environmental variable and checking whether the `adb` file exists there or not.

```
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
QStringList dirs = env.value("PATH").split(":");
foreach(QString p, dirs){
    QFileInfo check_file(p + "/" + "adb");
    if (check_file.exists() && check_file.isFile()) {
        qDebug() << "Yes!";
    }
}
```

By the way, I tested in on my linux machine and worked fine.

#### Windows

On Windows machines you would need to replace `adb` with `adb.exe` and `:` with `;`.

Comment: Guess you made a typo. Change `:` to `;` and it works properly ^^ Thank you.

Comment: @DarioAckermann In linux it's `:`, though in Windows it's `;`.